# How to load for the whole app a firestore request with a subscribe

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, request, observable, subscribe

I am working on an application with angular and firestore which requires to load all the data in realtime from a document for the whole application.

That is to say that when I arrive on the home page I need this data, on the same profile, etc ... For about 7, 8 pages.

I have this code that works pretty well:

in the service :

```
getMyUser() {
 this.usersCollection.doc<User>(this.authentificationService.getUid()).valueChanges().subscribe(result => 
 {
   return result;
 });
}
```

in the component :

```
this.userData = this.usersService.getMyUser();
```

However, this makes a request each time I enter the different pages. If I browse 8 pages that require this data, it will make 8 requests. I would like to find a solution to make the request only once with live data in a service, then display the data in my 8 different pages.

Is there a solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `shareReplay` operator can help you. Please refer this https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable in service equal to the result of the getUser call, then get the variable from the service instead of calling getUser.

Comment: You can just use a getter for the service variable, same way as you use getUser. Instead just return the service variable in your call instead of simply doing service.variable. Let me know if this answer works for you by marking it as an answer.

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong .. I make my request in the service and I assign each result (example a name and a first name) to a service variable. I then create a method to return each result (example getName and getFirstName) which just returns the variable. However, in the different pages, it makes a get of the variable but it does not have realtime update because I simply make a return of the variable. How to do it in real-time?

Comment: In real time, you're going to have to update the User in your service whenever changes are made. So for example, if someone makes a change to the user, it shouldn't just change the user in the component where the change is made, it should also change the user being stored in the service.

Answer (score 0):

`shareReplay` should work for the usecase you mention.  You can follow [this guide](http://www.jiodev.com/angular/learn-rxjs/shareReplay) and I'll leave a quick example as well.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { shareReplay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const CACHE_SIZE = <SIZE_FOR_YOUR_CACHE>;

////////
your additional code

//////////

private cache$: Observable<Array<User>>;

getMyUser() {
   if (!this.cache$) {
      this.cache$ = this.requestMyUser().pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
   }
   return this.cache$; 
}

requestMyUser(){
   this.usersCollection.doc<User> 
   (this.authentificationService.getUid()).valueChanges().subscribe(result => 
      {
         return result;
   });
}

/////
Rest of your code

/////
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check this !